# While loop checking multiprocessing

Tags: python, while-loop, multiprocessing

I have a while loop on my code checking a change on a file. If the file has changed I start a whole process, but I would like to keep checking if the file has a new changed and if it has again a new change put this new process in queue.
I have tried multiprocessing but it not the same I want.

I attach my code here:

```py
def newpick(driver,mainpage):
    initial = read_pick()
    while True:
        current = read_pick()
        if initial != current:
            for line in current:
                if line not in initial:
                    print(line)
            initial = current
            t =threading.Thread(target=start,args=(driver,mainpage,current))
            t.start()  #start the whole process
            t.join()   #let the previous process finish before start the next one
```

Comment: I have a feeling someone has solved this before, have you looked at: https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog

Comment: It should be possible to achieve that behaviour using multiprocessing. In what way was it not working for you? Could you post your multiprocessing-based code to help demonstrate what your issue was?

Comment: Hello Rob. I have update my code. I've also tried with pool but it does not work

Comment: Finally, I've asked myself. The problem was I don't let the script finish and an error appear. Thank you